# Why can't I send json with request using guzzle in php?

Tags: php, guzzle

I made a custom wrapper for guzzle:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiClient
{
    private $client;
    private $request;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://api-dev',
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.api+json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer 1|ELDPW0oOjBDDuR6rKxh3d94QzVjYC6T2PX41o6v1'
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function header(array $headers)
    {
        $this->request['headers'] = $headers;

        return $this;
    }

    public function body($body)
    {
        $this->request['body'] = $body;

        return $this;
    }

    public function options(array $options)
    {
        $this->request['options'] = $options;

        return $this;
    }

    public function formParams($formParams)
    {
        $this->request['form_params'] = $formParams;

        return $this;
    }

    public function json($json)
    {
        $this->request['json'] = $json;

        return $this;
    }

    public function debug()
    {
        $this->request['debug'] = true;

        return $this;
    }

    public function get($url)
    {
        $this->request['method'] = 'GET';
        $this->request['url'] = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function post($url)
    {
        $this->request['method'] = 'POST';
        $this->request['url'] = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function put($url)
    {
        $this->request['method'] = 'PUT';
        $this->request['url'] = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function delete($url)
    {
        $this->request['method'] = 'DELETE';
        $this->request['url'] = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $options = [];

        if (isset($this->request['body'])) {
            $options['body'] = $this->request['body'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request['form_params'])) {
            $options['form_params'] = $this->request['form_params'];
        }

        $response = $this->client->request(
            $this->request['method'],
            $this->request['url'],
            $options,
        );

        return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
    }
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
<?php

require 'ApiClient.php';

$api = new ApiClient();

$data = [
    'frame' => 0,
    'slot' => 0,
    'port' => 1,
    'ont_id' => 0,
];

$json_body = json_encode($data);

$response = $api->get('wan-info/41')->formParams($json_body)->send();

print_r($response);
```

Now, the error I'm getting is:

> PHP Warning:  http_build_query() expects parameter 1 to be array,
> string given in
> /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line
> 364 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException:
> Client error: `GET https://api-dev/wan-info/41`
> resulted in a `422 Unprocessable Content` response: {"message":"The
> frame field is required. (and 3 more errors)","errors":{"frame":["The
> frame field is required."],"slot": (truncated...)  in
> /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(72):
> GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create()
> #1 /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(209):
> GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}()
> #2 /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(158):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler()
> #3 /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/TaskQueue.php(52):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::GuzzleHttp\Promise{closure}()
> #4 /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php(251):
> GuzzleHttp\Promise\TaskQueue->run()
> #5 /var in /var/www/html/entropia/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php
> on line 113

I'm sure this is working on postman

Comment: I don't think `form_params` is what you should be using for a JSON request body.